# css rotation without pausing

Tags: css, css-animations

I have this little image that I want to rotate continuously or at least have a shorter break between animations.

Here's a gif of the behaviour (it's a bit ugly because of my gif-record-software, but the pause is the thing I wish to highlight here):

[image]

My css (less):

```css
.add{
vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left:5px;
    svg{
        fill:@colorOnBright;
        max-width: 30px;
        max-height: 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}

.animated {
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

markup:

```
<svg class="add animated" click.delegate="Add()">
     <use xlink:href="#add"></use>
</svg>
```

So, how do I get rid of the pause? or alternatively make the pause shorter.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I can't make sense of this.. I've tried recreating the thing in a pen, and it works just fine. Is there some other css-property that interferes with the animation somehow?

https://codepen.io/litari/pen/ajdpjp

**edit2:**
If I inspect and view the animations, I get this:
[image]

So it goes from 0 to 360 degrees at 25% and for the remaining 75% it just stays at 360deg.

Comment: Have you tried changing animation-timing-function: ease; to animation-timing-function: linear; ?

Comment: or : ease-in-out . You have no pause in your animation, it only jumps 1 degree to restarts. (full rotation is 360deg)  ease-in-out demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaLgNZ

Comment: Neither linear nor eas-in-out worked for me. Still get that same pause

Comment: then you need to add a few more steps to your animation and tune these to result you expect (-webkit- prefix are no longer required or should also be used on keyframes and animation .... )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, replace:

```css
.animated {
  animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

with:

```css
.animated {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

> The linear timing-function value maintains the same speed throughout the animation.

<sup>https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/understanding-css-timing-functions/#linear</sup>

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.animated {
  animation-name: rotation;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  transform-origin: center;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.linear {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated">+</div>
<p>and with linear:</p>
<div class="animated linear">+</div>
```

Comment: I've added a pen in the post. Works fine there, but not in my code :S

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson I just added snippet to my answer so you can see that it's working.

Comment: About your edit: 1. maybe there is another role (from a framework or anything) that it override your style. 2. If you aren't. somehow, using `from` and `to` but custom numbers of percentages.

Comment: I'm using Aurelia. I'll inspect the element and see if there is something strange going on. If I follow your snippet, mine still pauses.

Comment: Mine spins faster too. And the pause is related to my duration. So I think that when I have 2s duration, it spins for 1s and pauses for 1s

Comment: It's not make sense unless something else override your animation. Try to replace the class of the `.animated` element to something else (`.blabla` for example). My guess is that another library are targeting the class `animated`.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `animation-timing-function: linear` and `-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)` works fine

```css
        .animated {
          width: 50px;
          height: 50px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background: black;
          animation-name: rotation;
          animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
        }
        
        @keyframes rotation {
          from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          }
          to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
          }
        }
         
        .ball{
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
         }
```

```html
        
        <div class="animated">
          <div class="ball"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Still no difference :S I've tried both FF and chrome. Your example works, but mine still pauses..

Comment: Try clearing your browser history. And if possible send me your code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try  using this small change

```
 animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 3s;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! There was already an animation called rotation somewhere in my project. Changed the name and everything works fine.

Thanks all for your answers